# 新規登録時にエラー画面に遷移してしまう

Tags: java-ee

JavaEEにて部署管理アプリを作成しています。
新規データ登録時に部署番号がデータベースで重複している場合、画面上にエラーメッセージを表示したいのですが、現状コードでは重複時のエラーは表示されるのですが、非重複時の新規登録でエラー画面（用意しているxhtml）に遷移してしまいます。
原因をご教授頂けますと幸いです。

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>部署編集</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/practice2016/css/practice2016.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="center">
            <h1>部署編集</h1>
        </div>
        <h:messages styleClass="facesMessage" errorClass="error" />
        <h:form>
            <div class="frame2">
                <div class="search">
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">ID</span>
                        <span class="input1"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.id}" disabled="#{editBean.disableId}" label="ID" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">部署番号</span>
                        <span class="input2"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.deptNo}" disabled="#{editBean.disableDeptNo}" maxlength="9" label="部署番号" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">部署名</span>
                        <span class="input3"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.deptName}" maxlength="20" label="部署名" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="label">場所</span>
                        <span class="input4"><h:inputText value="#{editBean.loc}" maxlength="20" label="場所" size="13"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search2">
                    <h:commandButton class="return" action="#{editBean.back()}" value="戻る" immediate="true"/>
                    <h:commandButton class="save" action="#{editBean.save()}" value="保存" />
                    <h:commandButton class="delete" action="#{editBean.delete()}" value="削除" onclick="return confirm('削除しますか？');"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
/**
 * 編集画面のバッキングBean
 */
@Model
@ViewScoped
public class EditBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private EditLogic logic;
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message="{errors.required}")
    private String deptName;

    @Min(value=1)
    @NotNull(message="{errors.required}")
    private Integer deptNo;

    private String loc;
    private Integer versionNo;
    private boolean disableId;
    private boolean disableDeptNo;

    /**
     * @return id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id セットする id
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return deptName
     */
    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    /**
     * @param deptName セットする deptName
     */
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    /**
     * @return deptNo
     */
    public Integer getDeptNo() {
        return deptNo;
    }
    /**
     * @param  セットする deptNo
     */
    public void setDeptNo(Integer deptNo) {
        this.deptNo = deptNo;
    }
    /**
     * @return loc
     */
    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }
    /**
     * @param loc セットする loc
     */
    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }
    /**
     * @return versionNo
     */
    public Integer getVersionNo() {
        return versionNo;
    }
    /**
     * @param versionNo セットする versionNo
     */
    public void setVersionNo(Integer versionNo) {
        this.versionNo = versionNo;
    }
    /**
     * @return disableId
     */
    public boolean isDisableId() {
        return disableId;
    }
    /**
     * @param disableId セットする disableId
     */
    public void setDisableId(boolean disableId) {
        this.disableId = disableId;
    }
    /**
     * @return disableDeptNo
     */
    public boolean isDisableDeptNo() {
        return disableDeptNo;
    }
    /**
     * @param disableDeptNo セットする disableDeptNo
     */
    public void setDisableDeptNo(boolean disableDeptNo) {
        this.disableDeptNo = disableDeptNo;
    }


    /**
     * 初期処理
     */
    @PostConstruct
    @Auth
    public void init(){
        if(FlashUtil.get("id") != null){
            this.setId(Long.valueOf(FlashUtil.get("id")));
            logic.init(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 戻るボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String back(){
        // 検索画面に戻る
        return "/views/dept/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    /**
     * 保存ボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String save(){
        logic.save(this);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 削除ボタン押下時処理
     * @param id
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String delete(){
        logic.delete(this);
        return back();
    }
}
```

```java
/**
 * 編集画面のビジネスロジック
 */
@Stateless
public class EditLogicImpl implements EditLogic {

    @Inject
    private DeptDao dao;

    /**
     * 初期処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void init(EditBean bean){
        Long id = bean.getId();
        if(id != null){
            Dept dept = dao.findById(id);
            bean.setId(dept.getId());
            bean.setDeptName(dept.getDeptName());
            bean.setDeptNo(dept.getDeptNo());
            bean.setLoc(dept.getLoc());
            bean.setVersionNo(dept.getVersionNo());
            bean.setDisableId(true);
            bean.setDisableDeptNo(true);
        }
        if(bean.getVersionNo() == null){
            bean.setVersionNo(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 保存処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void save(EditBean bean){
        Dept dept = new Dept();
        dept.setId(bean.getId());
        dept.setDeptName(bean.getDeptName());
        dept.setDeptNo(bean.getDeptNo());
        dept.setLoc(bean.getLoc());
        if(bean.getVersionNo() != null){
            dept.setVersionNo(bean.getVersionNo());
        }else{
            dept.setVersionNo(0);
        }

        if((dao.findDeptNo(bean.getDeptNo())) != null){
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage("", CommonUtil.getFacesInfoMessage("messages.add.error.dept.duplicate"));
        }else{
            if(bean.isDisableId()){
                // 更新
                dao.update(dept);
                bean.setVersionNo(dept.getVersionNo());
            }else{
                // 新規登録
                dao.insert(dept);
                bean.setDisableId(true);
                bean.setDisableDeptNo(true);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 削除処理
     * @param bean 編集画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(EditBean bean){
        // 削除
        dao.delete(bean.getId());
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * 部署テーブルのDAO
 *
 */
@Stateless
public class DeptDao extends AbstractDao {

    /**
     * 全部署を取得
     * @return
     */
    public List<Dept> findAll(){
        // 全件取得
        return em.createQuery(em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Dept.class)).getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * 部署取得
     * @param id 部署ID
     * @return 部署
     */
    public Dept findById(long id){
        return em.find(Dept.class, id);
    }

    /**
     * 部署一覧取得
     * @param id 部署ID
     * @param deptNo 部署番号
     * @param deptName 部署名
     * @param location 場所
     * @return
     */
    public List<Dept> find(Long id, Integer deptNo, String deptName, String location){
        // クエリの生成
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Dept> query = cb.createQuery(Dept.class);
        Root<Dept> r = query.from(Dept.class);

        // SELECTを生成
        query.select(r);

        // WHEREを生成
        List<Predicate> wheres = new ArrayList<>();
        if(id != null) wheres.add(cb.equal(r.get(Dept_.id), id));
        if(deptNo != null) wheres.add(cb.equal(r.get(Dept_.deptNo), deptNo));
        if(deptName != null && !deptName.equals("")) wheres.add(cb.like(r.get(Dept_.deptName), "%" + deptName + "%"));
        if(location != null && !location.equals("")) wheres.add(cb.like(r.get(Dept_.loc), "%" + location + "%"));
        query.where(wheres.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        query.orderBy(cb.asc(r.get(Dept_.deptNo)));

        // クエリを実行
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * 部署登録
     * @param dept 登録する部署
     * @return
     */
    public void insert(Dept dept){
        // insert
        em.persist(dept);
    }

    /**
     * 部署更新
     * @param dept 更新する部署
     */
    public void update(Dept dept){
        // versionNo更新
        dept.setVersionNo(dept.getVersionNo() + 1);

        // update
        em.merge(dept);
    }

    /**
     * 部署削除
     * @param id 削除する部署のID
     */
    public void delete(long id){
        // select & delete
        em.remove(findById(id));
    }

    /**
     * 検索したDEPT_NOと一致するDEPT_NOを取得
     */
    public Integer findDeptNo(Integer deptNo) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Integer> query = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);
        Root<Dept> r = query.from(Dept.class);
        //SELECT文でDEPT_NOを取得
        query.select(r.get(Dept_.deptNo));
        //WHERE文でDEPT_NOと一致する条件指定
        query.where(cb.equal(r.get(Dept_.deptNo), deptNo));
        return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: この場合、質問は「新規登録時にエラーになってしまう」が主題になりませんか？また、具体的にどんなエラーが出ているのかを質問文に含めておくと回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かにタイトルが内容と合っていなかったです。エラー画面に遷移してしまうのですが、画像を添付した方がよいですかね。。。

Comment: エラーというのはあくまで自分で用意した画面、ということですね (プログラム自体の Fatal エラーの類かと思っていました)。その内容が伝わっていればとりあえずはOKだと思います。

Comment: 言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。今後気を付けたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
/**
     * 検索したDEPT_NOと一致するDEPT_NOを取得
     */
    public Integer findDeptNo(Integer deptNo) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Integer> query = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);
        Root<Dept> r = query.from(Dept.class);
        //SELECT文でDEPT_NOを取得
        query.select(r.get(Dept_.deptNo));
        //WHERE文でDEPT_NOと一致する条件指定
        query.where(cb.equal(r.get(Dept_.deptNo), deptNo));
        return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    }
```

getSingleResultでNoResultExceptionの例外処理をしていなかったことが原因でした。有難うございました。